# Delete based on timestamp grouping

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause, inner-join, date-arithmetic

I am trying to delete from MySql table based on a timestamp grouping.  Similar to what I have in a `GROUP BY` but delete the records based on the similar timestamp grouping.  Is this possible?  Delete all records that fall withing a 10 min range of the supplied timestamp.

```
DELETE c.* FROM commissions c 
LEFT JOIN comm_manuf_link ml ON (c.id = ml.comm_id)
LEFT JOIN manuf m ON (ml.manuf_id = m.id)
WHERE m.id = '21'
AND c.datestamp = UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2023-07-20 10:53:17') / 600;
```

The `SELECT` `GROUP BY` just for example purposes:

```
GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(c.datestamp) DIV 600
```

Comment: Do you want to have only one row for every 10 minute segment?

Comment: @Inventor I am grouping it that way on the SELECT but once I have them I want to delete that same grouping under the `m.id` of '21'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition should be:

```
c.datestamp >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2023-07-20 10:53:17') - 600
AND
c.datestamp <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2023-07-20 10:53:17') + 600
```

or:

```
c.datestamp BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2023-07-20 10:53:17') - 600 AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2023-07-20 10:53:17') + 600
```

or:

```
ABS(c.datestamp - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2023-07-20 10:53:17')) <= 600
```

Also, the condition `m.id = '21'` in the `WHERE` clause changes your `LEFT` joins to `INNER` joins because it filters out all the unmatched rows.

Also, there is no point for the join to `manuf` since the value of the column `id` of `manuf` can be retrieved from the column `manuf_id` of the table `comm_manuf_link`.

Write the query like this:

```
DELETE c.* 
FROM commissions c INNER JOIN comm_manuf_link ml 
ON c.id = ml.comm_id
WHERE ml.manuf_id = '21'
  AND c.datestamp >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2023-07-20 10:53:17') - 600
  AND c.datestamp <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2023-07-20 10:53:17') + 600;
```